# Playing image sequences in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, video, sequence

Greetings to all of you.

I have this somewhat frustrating problem, and I hope that you kindly help me solve it.

I am developing a human tracking system in MATLAB, and would like to show the result in an appealing GUI (also in MATLAB using GUIDE).

There is this main window where an image sequence of about 2500 gray scale images of size 320x240 would be played like a video but where the humans be outlined in them nicely.

The challenge is; these images need a bit of processing (detection outlining of humans) before being shown on the window.

Now, is it possible to display a set of images while at the same time do some processing for another set to be shown afterwards?

I would very much prefer it to play like a normal video, but I guess that would be somehow ambitious.

Comment: just a thought: how about doing the processing, and capturing the result of each image. Then play the whole thing as a movie in near real-time..

Comment: @Amro Hey man, good to hear from you again.

Comment: As I said, there are 2500 images, and doing the processing for each will consume a lot of time and it will be too late anyway to show the result. But this will be the last resort if no other solution can be found.

Comment: no I meant go through all the images NOT showing anything, and simply storing the result of the processing. Once done, you can show the resulting images one-by-one like a movie (you can even save it as an actual video file)

Comment: Interesting. But wouldn't that kill the real-time purpose of such application? I mean, usually they're embedded or linked with thermal cameras. Anyway, what kind of functions/techniques would I need to achieve your proposal?

Comment: @Amro I forgot to notify you.

Comment: There is a demo in IPT toolbox showing the concept: http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexbatch.html

Comment: How long does it take to process one image? How slow is your 'movie' if you display image n, process image n+1, display image n + 1, process image n+2 in series? Because if that is too slow, then I imagine the only thing you can do is to optimize your processing step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing a scenario similar to what you described. This was adapted from the [demo](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexbatch.html) I mentioned in the comments.

```
function ImgSeqDemo()
    figure()
    for i=1:10
        %# read image
        img = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );

        %# process image to extract some object of interest
        [BW,rect] = detectLargestCell(img);

        %# show image
        imshow(img), hold on

        %# overlay mask in red color showing object
        RGB = cat(3, BW.*255, zeros(size(BW),'uint8'), zeros(size(BW),'uint8'));
        hImg = imshow(RGB); set(hImg, 'AlphaData',0.5);

        %# show bounding rectangle
        rectangle('Position', rect, 'EdgeColor','g');
        hold off

        drawnow
    end
end
```

Here is the processing function used above. In your case, you would insert your algorithm instead:

```
function [BW,rect] = detectLargestCell(I)
    %# OUTPUT
    %#    BW    binary mask of largest detected cell
    %#    rect  bounding box of largest detected cell

    %# find components
    [~, threshold] = edge(I, 'sobel');
    BW = edge(I,'sobel', threshold*0.5);
    se90 = strel('line', 3, 90);
    se0 = strel('line', 3, 0);
    BW = imdilate(BW, [se90 se0]);
    BW = imclearborder(BW, 4);
    BW = bwareaopen(BW, 200);
    BW = bwmorph(BW, 'close');
    BW = imfill(BW, 'holes');

    %# keep largest component
    CC = bwconncomp(BW);
    stats = regionprops(CC, {'Area','BoundingBox'});
    [~,idx] = max([stats.Area]);
    rect = stats(idx).BoundingBox;
    BW(:) = 0;
    BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 1;
end
```

[image: screenshot]